# Barcode technology -- smartphone apps

Tags: iphone, ios, barcode, barcode-scanner, smartphone

I was wondering what type of technology is used in the apps that can scan a barcode and output data that that barcode represents. What type of programming would the app use to access the camera and be able to read a certain barcode?

if type of smartphone matters then specifically IOS.

Comment: i think you check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779477/various-barcode-reader-free-sdk-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/) framework in your code to have a barcode reader in your IOS app...

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, you can use the AVFoundation framework to scan barcodes natively. Here's a tutorial to get you started http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx

If you need to support older versions of iOS, the ZBar library, which emreoktem has linked in his answer, is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

i think here is the some demo code and also demo of app here
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779477/various-barcode-reader-free-sdk-in-ios`